# How can I upgrade rpm on Centos 7 offline?

Tags: linux, python, centos, centos-7, rpm

I'm trying to install python modules on centos 7 and python2-setuptools-45.2.0-1.noarch requires rpmlib(PayloadIsZstd) <= 5.4.18-1

I have so far installed epel-release-latest-7.noarch by downloading the file on a different computer and transfering by using usb. But I can not find something similar for updating rpm.

How can I update rpm to handle this offline?

Comment: AFAIK `python2-setuptools-45.2.0-1.noarch` is not a CentOS 7 package. .... And no python2-setuptools in EPEL https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/p/ .... Suggest : Install setuptools manually : https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/